# Dealing with NPM and Bower registry entries when moving a GitHub repository to an organization

Tags: github, npm, bower, github-organizations

I have a couple of related projects on GitHub that I want to group under a new organization. However, these projects are already registered on both NPM and Bower.

How can I prevent/minimize disruptions to projects in the wild that might be using these NPM/Bower dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After moving an existing repository to another user or organization as the new owner, GitHub provides automatic URL redirection for any URLs that point to the old repository.

Just make sure that you update any references to the old repository within your repository such as your bower.json/package.json or README file or the repository website URL on GitHub (especially if you're using gh-pages). Also make sure you update your remote:

```
git remote set-url origin <new repository URL>
```

For NPM registration, you need to cut a new tag and publish the new tag in NPM. NPM picks up new information that's in package.json (like the new reposistory URL). For example:

```
npm version patch
git push origin master --tags
npm publish
npm info <component name>
```

For Bower, you have to first unregister your component and the re-register it. Luckily, Bower has recently introduced the [unregister](http://bower.io/docs/api/#unregister) command that allows you to unregister your components yourself. You just need to be one of the contributors to the repository and login to Bower using your GitHub credentials, unregister your component and then re-register it:

```
bower version patch
git push origin master --tags
bower login
bower unregister <component name>
bower register <component name> <new repository URL>
bower info <component name>
```